# How to read this list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

I need a little help with understanding, or like how to read these kind of comprehension

```
[word[1:-1:2] for word in ['Norway', 'Sweden', 'Denmark'] if 'r' in word]

h = [2*x for x in range(10) if divmod(x, 2)[1] == 0]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you can just paste these onto the python command line and try them

Comment: If you wonder what the `word[1:-1:2]` does or means, check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: Or just try it:  `[i for i in '123456789'[1:-1:2]]` yields `['2', '4', '6', '8']`

Comment: i also have some trouble understanding how divmod function works

Comment: @ineedsomehelp it's a slightly overly complex way of checking if the number is an even number, if the remainder after being divided by 2 is 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, go from right to left for each `for`.

First example:

`for word in ['Norway', 'Sweden', 'Denmark'] if 'r' in word`:

For each word that contains the letter r

`word[1, -1, 2]`

add word to list, with special modifications to word.

Second example:

`for x in range(10) if divmod(x, 2)[1] == 0`

for each x as single digit number, if the remainder of x / 2 is 0

`2**x`

add 2**x to list.

In more complicated, nested for loops case, this will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
[word[1:-1:2] for word in ['Norway', 'Sweden', 'Denmark'] if 'r' in word]
```

is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for word in ['Norway', 'Sweden', 'Denmark']:
    if 'r' in word:
        result.append(word[1:-1:2])
```

```
h = [2*x for x in range(10) if divmod(x, 2)[1] == 0]
```

is equivalent to:

```
h = []
for x in range(10):
    if divmod(x, 2)[1] == 0:
        h.append(2*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern to list comprehensions is

```
[what to do - for loop - optional if statement]
```

which spans out to (exmaple 1)

```
output_list = []
for word in ['Norway', 'Sweden', 'Denmark']:
  if 'r' in word:
    output_list.append(word[1:-1:2])
```

and example 2:

```
h = []
for x in range(10):
    if divmod(x, 2)[1] == 0:
        h.append(2*x)
```

Comment: Maybe add the example 2's spanned out for loop?